# SQL Join where row exists in single table

Tags: sql-server

I suspect this has been answered before however I can't seem to find a post that matches what I am trying to accomplish.

I have the following stored procedure. This procedure is only producing results based on the first IN clause and not the second.

```
USE [asl]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[aslGetCommonv1]    Script Date: 10/04/2020 3:46:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aslGetCommonv1]
    @StartDate varchar(10),
    @EndDate varchar(10),
    @GroupBy varchar(100),
    @Select varchar(100)
AS
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @SQL = @Select + '
    COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM dbo.requests_services rqs
    LEFT JOIN services      svc ON svc.service_id = rqs.service_id
    LEFT JOIN requests         rq ON rq.request_id = rqs.request_id
    LEFT JOIN doctors          do ON do.doctor_id  = rq.doctor_id
    WHERE rqs.service_id IN (1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1401, 1402, 1404, 1405, 1407, 1408, 1410, 1501, 1503, 1504, 1505, 1506, 1509, 5101, 5103) OR
    svc.service_abbrev IN (SADREN, SADREN2, SFH28, SLPSAL, TFT, CTA, VITD, U216 OH, U2416 OH, UEMET, CALP, FAEPCR, CDSA1, CDSA2, CDSA3, CDSA3+, CDSA4, CDSA4+, CDSA5, INTPERM, SIBO2, SIBO3, GIEFFCO, GIEFFME, CMAP,
    CMMR, IGA96, IGA96AS, IGG144, IGA144, IGG208, IGA208, IGG+A208, ALC050, ALC100, ALC150, ALC200, ALCPLAT, CYTOK, HIAM, DAO, KRPR, ENEUM, LIPOSCRN, INEUM, ANEUM, ORGANIX, UIODL, MTHFR, OM3INPR,
    ONCOSTAT, ONCONEXT, ONCONPLUS, ONCOTRACE, ONCOTRAIL, ONCOCOUNT, IMMUNOSTAT, NAGALASE, PRIMESPOT, CHEMOSNIP) AND rq.entry_date BETWEEN ' + @StartDate + ' AND ' + @EndDate + '
    GROUP BY ' + @GroupBy + '
    ORDER BY rqs.service_id ASC'

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

(Please ignore the fact the dates are varchar). Now, I believe that the reason for blank results from the second IN clause is that the table dbo.services is not referenced in the SELECT or JOIN statements - I just don't know to put it in there in the proper manner.

The "service_abbrev" column only exists in a single table (dbo.services). The only other column in this table is the "service_id" field, which as above is joined from dbo.requests_services column service_id.

So, what is the best way to get the table dbo.servcices referenced in the procedure so that results are returned from both IN clauses?

** EDIT **
So, I need to change the code to look like this for the date? BETWEEN ' + '@StartDate' + ' AND ' + '@EndDate' +

The strings SADREN, SADREN2, etc, are only accepted if I double quote them - could this be because I've not quoted the @Dates as above?

Also, here is the query I am using to test:

```
USE asl;

DECLARE @StartDate varchar(10)
SET @StartDate = '2018-02-01'

DECLARE @EndDate varchar(10)
SET @EndDate = '2019-06-20'

DECLARE @GroupBy VARCHAR(100)
SET @GroupBy = 'rqs.service_id,svc.service_abbrev'

DECLARE @Select VARCHAR(100)
SET @Select = 'SELECT rqs.service_id,svc.service_abbrev,'

EXEC dbo.aslGetCommonv1 @StartDate, @EndDate, @GroupBy, @Select
```

Comment: what are those `SADREN`, `SADREN2` ? Are they value or column name ?

Comment: you can first try printing the dynamic sql and running it separately to check if that runs fine or not.

Comment: SADREN, SADREN2, SFH28, etc are being treated as column names if they are supposed to be treated as strings they should be quoted.

Comment: ' dbo.services is not referenced in the SELECT or JOIN' - yes it is?

Comment: If I try to run a query against the procedure in it's current state I do get invalid table names for SADREN, SADREN2, etc.
With a single quotation mark at the beginning and end of each value, I get Incorrect syntax near 'SADREN'. when trying to alter the procedure.
If I add 2 single quotes to the start and end of each, there are no errors in the procedure or query, but there are no results based on the non-numerical values.

Comment: Can you provide sample data as text or to a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

There a are a number of things wrong.

1. `SADREN`, `SADREN2`, `SFH28` etc are strings and should be single quoted
2. `BETWEEN ' + @StartDate + ' AND ' + @EndDate +`  - the dates need to be quoted
3. you have a `group by` but the `group by` column is not included in the `select` clause
4. the `order by` column is not included in the `select` so is invalid.

Other than that the query *works*. You can debug this by generating the sql statement, selecting it having change the query option in ssms to text and then running it (without executing).

Comment: I've edited the question to include more information. Thank you